# Runnin shell script from AIR app

Tags: shell, air

Can an AIR app that is distributed as .air package run a shell script?

Comment: Please show some code, add SDK versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. See [File.openWithDefaultApplication()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#openWithDefaultApplication%28%29) - all shell scripts are thorougly listed among file types **prohibited** to launch. Moveover, even native packaged AIR app can't run NativeProcess using bat file - it must run cmd.exe with arguments (I'm talking about Windows, but this must be symmetrical on all systems.)
If you need to run the script, you need AIR 2.0+ and NativeProcess, pointed to script interpreter.